# How to compile android-arm64-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot from flutter engine

Tags: android, linux, flutter, arm64, flutter-engine

While building flutter apk on termux proot Ubuntu in release mode. Flutter gives following error about missing gen_snapshot.

```
anil@localhost:~/myapp/android$ ./gradlew assembleRelease

                                                     > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease

Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash.          Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code 254    Target android_aot_release_android-arm failed: ProcessException: Failed to find "/home/anil/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot" in the search path.

  Command: /home/anil/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot

Target android_aot_release_android-arm64 failed: ProcessException: Failed to find "/home/anil/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot" in the search path.

  Command: /home/anil/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot

Target android_aot_release_android-x64 failed: Exception: AOT snapshotter exited with code 254

                                                     

> Task :app:compileFlutterBuildRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Script '/home/anil/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command '/home/anil/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s

2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

anil@localhost:~/myapp/android$
```

I tried to copy ~/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-arm64-release/gen_snapshot to~/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot but this didn't work. Building flutter apk on arm64 Linux require specific android/gen_snapshot for compiling apk in release mode. I don't know how but compiling apk in debug mode work on arm64 Linux.

Comment: Possibly related: [Android release build failed on linux-arm64 (Termux) #109087](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109087)

Comment: Yes this issue is committed by me same problem due to missing gen_snaphot for android-arm64-release on linux-arm64.

Comment: More FYI, AOSP issue for [Support linux/arm64 Android tools](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227219818) as running tools on Termux would be similar situation.

Comment: The link you provided has issue with aapt2 which I have resolved but this gen_snapshot for android-arm64-release/linux-arm64/gen_snapshot file artifacts has to be built from flutter engine it's not a problem with Android SDK Or Flutter SDK, it is just an additional file which is downloaded by pub from flutter engine. I tried to build flutter engine on my device but it ran into some goma_ctl.py missing error. I thought it may be due to arm so I tried to do same in GCP x64 but ran into same missing file in chromium depot_tools.

Comment: If anyone have experience in building flutter engine please provide me this artifacts file for arm64 Linux.